# How to initialize sparse matrices with zeros?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I used this [Keras word-level text generation example](https://github.com/vlraik/word-level-rnn-keras/blob/master/lstm_text_generation.py) as a base for my own work.

As I tried to train data on it, I got a *MemoryError* in line 59:

```
X = np.zeros((len(sentences), maxlen, len(words)), dtype=np.bool)
```

as a big matrix is initialized with zeros.
The same zero initialization will happen to y:

```
y = np.zeros((len(sentences), len(words)), dtype=np.bool)
```

Later on the matrices will be filled like that (one hot encoding):

```
for i, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    for t, word in enumerate(sentence.split()):
        X[i, t, word_indices[word]] = 1
    y[i, word_indices[next_words[i]]] = 1
```

**How can I use sparse matrices to save memory and make it executable?**

I looked at [scipy's sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html), but it looked like they only support 2D matrices.
I also looked at [Tensorflow's sparse tensor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor) but I think they don't support zero initialization to fill them in later (like I need).

Comment: If you are using for loop then its not vectorizing. Try will scikit `HashVectorizer` to get the sparse matrix.

Comment: Use a reshaped 2D sparse matrix instead?

Comment: @Bharathshetty How can I use the scikit `HashingVectorizer` to create a matrix filled with zeros? I don't see this capability in the [docs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.transform).

Comment: Am late to the party by it's similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538692/using-sparse-matrices-with-keras-and-tensorflow