# Why can't my sparse tensor convert to a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, sparse-matrix

I want to feed a sparse tensor as input to a simple tensorflow-based recurrent neural network. For that I use the following code:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.Input(shape=(1, features_dim), sparse=True))
model.add(keras.layers.RNN(keras.layers.SimpleRNNCell(hidden_layer_dim, activation="sigmoid")))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(labels_dim, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=learning_rate, momentum=0.0, decay=0.0, nesterov=False),
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=[keras.metrics.SparseCategoricalAccuracy()])

model.fit(
      training_data, 
      training_labels,
      epochs=num_epochs, 
      batch_size=batch_size, 
      shuffle=True
    )
```

`features_dim` denotes the number features, `training_labels` is a NumPy array containing the respective labels and training_data is a sparse tensor created from a sparse matrix in COO-format with the shape ([num_entries, 1, num_features]).

However, when I try to run this I get this error:

> TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.sparse_tensor.SparseTensor'> to Tensor. Contents: SparseTensor(indices=Tensor("cond_1/Identity:0", shape=(None, 3), dtype=int64, device=/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0), values=Tensor("cond_1/Identity_1:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float64, device=/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0), dense_shape=Tensor("stack:0", shape=(3,), dtype=int64, device=/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0)). Consider casting elements to a supported type.

I'm a bit lost about this error. I was under the impression that TensorFlow can handle sparse data without having to convert it. Furthermore, if a conversion is necessary, I'm not sure why it fails. I can run the code above (without sparse=True) *just fine*, if I convert the sparsetensor **manually** using `tf.sparse.to_dense()`. Thus there does not seem to be anything wrong with how I created the sparsetensor from the coo-matrix (at least not as far as I can tell).

Edit:

I have now tested the answers provided in
[Using sparse matrices with Keras and Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538692/using-sparse-matrices-with-keras-and-tensorflow) extensively. Unfortunately, neither of them solves my problem without sacrificing at least the sparsity of the batch. Is there no other possibility?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using sparse matrices with Keras and Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41538692/using-sparse-matrices-with-keras-and-tensorflow)

Comment: It should probably work, but I would prefer not to have to make the batches dense. The input space dimension is pretty high, so holding even just the mini-batches as dense tensors in main memory is not ideal

Comment: But the second answer shows the way to go without converting input matrix.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply, I was pretty busy this week. I tried the second answer; however, I still get the same error. I could obviously densify each batch in the custom training loops, but this kinda defeats the purpose. While it would still help my memory problems, I also expect performance increases using sparse data (for comparison using a MLP, the runtime decreased by 90% when using a sparse representation of the data I'm working with).