# How to make Keras really support sparse matrix?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matrix, keras, sparse-matrix

I am trying to build my deep learning model using Keras and TensorFlow. My model needs to input a matrix as the features.

The matrix is too big to be fitted into the memory. Fortunately, however, the matrix is very sparse. So I use `scipy.sparse.dok_matrix()` to store it.

The problem is Keras doesn't support a sparse matrix as the input(maybe TensorFlow does?). I searched on internet and found some solutions to this problem, just like this one: [Keras, sparse matrix issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37609892/keras-sparse-matrix-issue). It used a `.todense()` function to turn the sparse matrix to a dense one.

But these are stupid solutions. They are actually 'fake solutions', because if I could put a dense matrix into memory, why would I use a sparse one?

So anyone has 'real solutions' to this problem?

Comment: Will it be convolutional or similar to fully connected?

Comment: It's convolutional

Comment: Not as easy... :( -- I think if you can find tensorflow convolutions that support sparse images, then you can wrap them in keras layers.