# How can I avoid this Numpy ArrayMemoryError when using scikit-learn's DictVectorizer on my data?

Tags: numpy, memory, scikit-learn, out-of-memory, dictvectorizer

I'm getting a `numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError` when I try to use `scikit-learn`'s `DictVectorizer` on my data.

I'm using `Python 3.9` in `PyCharm` on `Windows 10`, and my system has 64 GB of RAM.

I'm pre-processing text data for training a Keras POS-tagger. The data starts in this format, with lists of tokens for each sentence:

```
sentences = [['Eorum', 'fines', 'Nervii', 'attingebant'], ['ait', 'enim'], ['scriptum', 'est', 'enim', 'in', 'lege', 'Mosi'], ...]
```

I then use the following function to extract useful features from the dataset:

```
def get_word_features(words, word_index):
    """Return a dictionary of important word features for an individual word in the context of its sentence"""
    word = words[word_index]
    return {
        'word': word,
        'sent_len': len(words),
        'word_len': len(word),
        'first_word': word_index == 0,
        'last_word': word_index == len(words) - 1,
        'start_letter': word[0],
        'start_letters-2': word[:2],
        'start_letters-3': word[:3],
        'end_letter': word[-1],
        'end_letters-2': word[-2:],
        'end_letters-3': word[-3:],
        'previous_word': '' if word_index == 0 else words[word_index - 1],
        'following_word': '' if word_index == len(words) - 1 else words[word_index + 1]
    }

word_dicts = list()
for sentence in sentences:
    for index, token in enumerate(sentence):
        word_dicts.append(get_word_features(sentence, index))
```

In this format the data isn't very large. It seems to only be about 3.3 MB.

Next I setup `DictVectorizer`, fit it to the data, and try to transform the data with it:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer

dict_vectoriser = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
dict_vectoriser.fit(word_dicts)
X_train = dict_vectoriser.transform(word_dicts)
```

At this point I'm getting this error:

```
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 499. GiB for an array with shape (334043, 200643) and data type float64
```

This seems to suggest that `DictVectorizer` has massively increased the size of the data, to nearly 500 GB. Is this normal? Should the output really take up this much memory, or am I doing something wrong?

I looked for solutions and [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57507832/unable-to-allocate-array-with-shape-and-data-type) someone suggested allocating more virtual memory by going into Windows settings and `SystemPropertiesAdvanced`, unchecking `Automatically manage paging file size for all drives`, then manually setting the paging file size to a sufficiently large amount. This would be fine if the task required about 100 GB, but I don't have enough storage to allocate 500 GB to the task.

Is there any solution for this? Or do I just need to go and buy myself a larger drive just to have a big enough pagefile? This seems impractical, especially when the initial dataset wasn't even particularly large.

Comment: Try without forcing a dense array (`sparse=False`)?

Comment: The memory requirement is consistent with the array shape, (334043, 200643).  Given the size of your `word_dicts`, and the `transform` docs, does that seem reasonable?  A fuller display of the error traceback may help identify what step is producing the error.

Comment: One of your features is `previous_word`. If you have 10K words that appear only once, that implies that the one-hot encoding for `previous_word` has to have 10K columns. Then, if you have 10K different sentences, that's a 10K by 10K array to hold these sentences, which could get big very quickly.

Comment: It does work when I don't force a dense array, @BenReiniger , but I need it to be dense for the next step, where I fit a `Keras` model to the data, so ultimately that doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @NickODell and @hpaulj , it sounds like I really am creating that much data in the transformation then. In that case, maybe there's some way to only create it bit-by-bit using a data generator? I have to use one later in my pipeline at any rate to feed my `Keras` model so as not to overload the GPU memory.

Comment: sparse to dense in a generator: https://stackoverflow.com/q/37609892/10495893

Comment: @BenReiniger That looked like a possible solution, but it doesn't seem to be working. Whether I put `x_batch.todense()` in my data generator or not, it results in this error when I try to run `model.fit`: `TypeError: sparse array length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]`, so I assume it's not actually being changed from sparse to dense for some reason.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the right solution path, but if it is, putting the traceback for that error and some code snippet in the question would let us try to help. For that matter, can you share (a version of) the dataset and code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a solution. In case it's useful to anybody, here it is. I had been using a data generator later in my workflow, just to feed data to the GPU for processing in batches.

```
class DataGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.x) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        return batch_x, batch_y
```

Based on the comments I got here I originally tried updating the output here to `return batch_x.todense()` and changing my code above so that `dict_vectoriser = DictVectorizer(sparse=True)`. As I mentioned in the comments, though, this didn't seem to work.

I've now changed the generator so that, once the `dict_vectoriser` is created and fitted to the data, it's passed as an argument to the data generator, and it's not called to transform the data until the generator is being used.

```
class DataGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size, x_vec):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.x_vec = x_vec

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.x) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x_vec.transform(self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size])
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        return batch_x, batch_y
```

To call it you need to set the `batch_size` and provide labels, so below `y_train` is some encoded list of labels corresponding to the `x_train` data.

```
dict_vectoriser = DictVectorizer(sparse=False)
dict_vectoriser.fit(word_dicts)
train_generator = DataGenerator(word_dicts, y_train, 200, dict_vectoriser)
```